# C# & WebDriver: Xpath Statement to a Web Driver Statement

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to click on a button using Selenium WebDriver using an Xpath Identifier.

The HTML for the button object is as follows:

```
<div class="button-wrap fr">
<a class="button blue-button submit"><span class="button-left"></span><span class="button-mid"><span class="text-button-ds">Email me the link<span>Email me the link</span></span></span><span class="button-right"></span></a>
</div>
```

I was able to get the Xpath for the button. It is as follows:

//*[@id="forget-password-form"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/a/span[2]

I would like to write a Web Driver statement that clicks the button using an Xpath statement.

However, what I have written is not working (See below)

```
submitButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='forget-password-form'][3]/[2]"));
submitButton.Click();
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: And you expect us to answer without knowing the html you use.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and *the shortest code necessary to reproduce it* in the question itself

Comment: HI EZI - Desired Behavior is Web Driver statement that clicks the button using an Xpath statement (which was included in the original post). Also, HTML snippet was also included. Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything like `forget-password-form` in your html, Am I wrong? So how can we be check whether `//div[@id='forget-password-form'][3]/[2]` is correct or not? Thanks....

Comment: This is how I retrieved the Xpath: Open site in Chrome. Right-click the button and select Inspect Element. Right-Click on the Element and select Copy Xpath. Paste text into Stack Overflow post. Done.

Comment: OK, Which site? Can I get the same html if I do the same with this page?????  I see, you want to have fun with us. Both ignorant and arrogant. Good features.

Comment: I have no time for this. Goodbye.

Answer (score 0):

As an FYI, the following lines located the button and clicked it:

```
submitButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='button-mid']"));
submitButton.Click();
```

Cheers